# Unix Regex: No line longer than 70 characters in a text file

Tags: regex, unix, newline

I need to use a regex in unix to make sure no line in a text document is over 70 characters, and I just cannot find the right expression. I've been trying:

```
sed "s/\(^.{70}\)/\1\n\r/g" firstMondayNoParas2.txt > firstMondayLined.txt
```

This expression isn't working though. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your question about regexp, or about cutting a file to 70-width? Because `cut -c1-70 < firstMondayLined.txt` is way easier...

Comment: Get rid of `\r` in the replacement. Unix lines end with `\n`, not `\n\r`. Also, this will only put a newline after the first 70 characters. If the line is more than 140 characters, the second line will still be longer than 70.

Comment: Even on Windows, lines end with `\r\n` and not `\n\r`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape also the curly braces.

```
sed "s/^\(.\{70\}\)/\1\n\r/"
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'foobar' | sed 's/^\(.\{3\}\)/\1\n\r/'
foo
bar

$ echo 'foobar' | sed 's/^.\{3\}/&\n\r/'
foo
bar
```

If you want to cut for every 70 chars then you may try like this,

```
sed 's/.\{3\}/&\n/g' file
```

*Example:*

```
$ echo 'foobarbuzbu' | sed 's/.\{3\}/&\n/g'
foo
bar
buz
bu
```

You could use `perl` also.

```
$ echo 'foobarbuz' | perl -pe 's/(.{3})(?!$)/\1\n/g'
foo
bar
buz
```

`(.{3})(?!$)` would capture each three chars but not the one which was present at the last. So this won't add a extra new line character at the last if your input has chars multiple of 3. To do an in-place edit, you must need to add `-i` parameter like

```
perl -i -pe 's/(.{70})(?!$)/\1\n/g' file
```

Comment: Well this got it to actually newline after 70 characters, but it only does the first 70 characters. I have a line that is like 500 characters, and it only new lined the first 70. I assume a * or + needs to go somewhere.

Comment: That last command was close, except I don't want to newline every 70 characters, only after a line goes over 70 characters, if that makes sense.

Comment: if your system has perl installed , then you may use the perl solution.

Comment: @zaferoff both are same.

Comment: The perl command appeared to work! Thank you very much. I don't know much about the perl interpreter, so can you explain what the (?!$) is doing to the matched characters?

Comment: @zaferoff since you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)